# what does 'with n as adj' mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, adverbial-phrases, as

The sentence:

> A WSGI-compliant server or gateway should document what variables it provides, along with their definitions as appropriate.

How to understand **with their definitions as appropriate**?

either:

> with their appropriate definitions

or:

> with their definitions as it is appropriate

which one is correct?

Comment: It's not "with _n_ as _adj_" - you should regard _as appropriate_ as an idiom.

Comment: @ColinFine True, although there's also *as necessary, as desired*, etc.

Comment: _As appropriate_ = 'if it is appropriate in that particular case'.

Comment: Yes, @stangdon, there are several options. But the construction is not available for just any adjective.

Answer (score 2):

It means something like your second option, but your wording is also unclear.

I would paraphrase it as *insofar as (or "to the degree that") it is appropriate to do so*.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-reading it as "...*when* appropriate." and see if it makes more sense to you like that.

---

In many contexts such as this, the phrase *"...for X do Y as appropriate..."* indicates that doing Y may or may not be appropriate for every X, and so Y should only be done on a case-by-case basis.

Similar phrasings include *"as needed"* or *"as necessary"*.

---

As an example, let's imagine an ice-cream shop!

> As an ice-cream shop employee, you should take a new cone and fill it with the ice-cream of the customer's choice.  Then you should add toppings as requested.

Why do the instructions say *"as requested"*?  Because not all customers want toppings!  If the instructions only said *"... add toppings."* then following the instructions (too literally) would mean adding toppings for every customer.

A better wording in this example might be *"Then you should add any requested toppings."* but sometimes the *"... as required"* construction is just more appropriate.

---

Back to your example:

> [A WSGI-compliant server or gateway] should [document what variables it provides], [along with their definitions as appropriate].

Breaking the sentence into those main pieces, we can basically understand that last chunk to mean *"... and document the definitions for those variables as appropriate"*.

I cannot think of any reason why documentation for the definition of a variable would be inappropriate... but perhaps this choice of phrasing is being used more in a business-sense than a technical-sense so as to allow more wiggle-room if they ever get sued and want to argue that something wasn't *strictly* required.

Answer (score 0):

With *X* as *adjective* means:

- You are looping through a number of things, doing something to each thing.
- For each time you do something, you may encounter the condition *adjective*
- If that condition is true for the particular thing you are doing, *with X* applies.
- You won't know whether or not *adjective* is true until you start the loop (that's what the *as* communicates).

---

> An X should document what variables it provides, along with their definitions as appropriate.

is the same as saying

> An X should document what variables it provides.  During any time where it does this, while it is looping through each variable, the variable's definition should be documented *if* X determines documentation is appropriate for that variable.

Answer (score -2):

I can say this as I worked as a programmer for a number of years: too many people in information technology write poor English, and a few take pride in writing poor English. Your question involves just such a sentence.

Servers do not “document” anything. Nor do they “provide” variables. I think what is meant is

> The documentation for a WSGI-compliant server or gateway should list and define all supported variables.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.